# When your page has no results, what do you show?

Tags: tables, data-tables, pagination, empty

I am paginating a data table and have different views in my application where each view has its own rows. Some views may have data, some may not.

> Showing 1-0 of 0 Page 1 of 0

is what I am showing on a page with no rows.

If I had some rows to display, it would be

> Showing 1-30 of 45 Page 1 of 1

What do I display in the empty case?

Some possibilities:

1. > Showing 0-0 of 0 Page 1 of 1
2. > Showing 0-1 of 1 Page 1 of 1

What do I do here?

Comment: Sounds terrible, what's the reason for data not being available? Is this triggered by a user search?

Comment: @DarrylGodden i have financial data coming in from external APIs shown in the same table but divided as views, it takes me some time to get the data up and running on some views sometimes so if you load the website initially when it just boots it wont have anything to show, there is pagination but some views may have data some may not

Comment: @PirateApp "It takes some time"? So the area isn't "nothing matches your criteria" it's "still loading"?

Comment: There's some answers below, one of which seems quite popular, my view would be to look at refining the queries that pull in the data and the potential to make efficiencies at that end, alongside the queries and reduce the possibility that the user could end up with no data to show.

Comment: google solved this for android apps a long time ago by letting you provide an alternate view when a ListView has 0 items

Answer (score 107, accepted):

For this situation you can use an [empty state](https://uxplanet.org/downplaying-empty-states-in-design-fc367212b493) which can be just text or a graphic with text and an action button.

Example of an empty state from Product Hunt:

[image]

Good empty states will give the users an action button which can push them in the right direction. A button with something like "Rephrase your search" might work in this case.

It doesn't make sense to show any pagination because there are no results let alone one or even half a page of results.

Comment: Please only show that panel when you actually did search. I know too many unreliable web apps, which show "no results" when there was a timeout or even while performing the actual search.

Comment: Does their site _really_ say "bummer"? Gees.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit their voice and tone is a west coast surfer dude from the '90s.

Comment: Refining a research would only output fewer results, wouldn't it?

Comment: I agree with @EricDuminil, a better word would be reword or something similar.

Comment: That mistake in the sentence though(in screenshot)

Comment: @Brandito I edited it to "Rephrase your search".

Comment: @MatJ took way too long to find for me :(

Comment: @Brandito it might make you feel better that you were still faster than the QA of that site.

Comment: @EricDuminil Refining means improving on the current state, instead of trying again from scratch. Generally, one is overly generous at the start, because adding things back in can be harder to near impossible, so refining in that case means getting rid of more of the dross, but that is not universal.

Comment: `button with something like "Rephrase your search"` this sounds like the original input phrase isn't in a text field next to the "search" button when showing results. That is horrible thing to do, I hate when websites do that and it would be a reason for me to leave outright, *especially* if I get no results and I can't even see then seach query to check for spelling errors.

Comment: @kajacx I think it's implicit that you have your search input field next to the search button. In the absence of search results, a short copy explaining the circumstances and an extra call-to-action button that moves the focus back to the search field would only be beneficial.

Comment: Yea, if the search textfield and button are still visible, then an extra button is nice to have too.

Answer (score 43):

I would hide Showing "0 results from 0 results".
Instead I would add in place a Blank State image with a button for the user to add data. ( If the user adds the data ).

Displaying a pagination where there are no results is purely an artefact of a not so good UX.

Example : [image]

Comment: Sorry about a seemingly unrelated question, but what app is this?

Comment: Expensify is called. I don`t know anything about it.

Comment: Displaying pagination when there's 1 page or fewer of results is also not so good UX. Related, the site should recover gracefully if I am on page 3 and then alter the search term in the URL so it now gives a 1-page result.

Answer (score 20):

For completeness, there's a canonical **bad solution** to this that is extremely common: quietly (maybe even silently) generalize the user's query until the set of results is non-empty, and show them results that they weren't looking for. Sometimes this takes the form of guessing at other searches they might have meant, Other times it's just putting advertisements in their face.

Obviously (or maybe not so obviously, since it's so common), don't do this.

Comment: I actually like this feature in google. If you misspell something or search something with no results, it will try to figure out what you meant, and says at the top "Showing results for [X]." Perhaps that's "loud" enough so it doesn't qualify, but I think this can be done correctly.

Comment: Note: Google also includes a button for "Search instead for [X]," which is a requirement for this feature to be acceptable.

Comment: @JamesG.: It also does that when you *didn't* misspell your query but it's an uncommon or foreign word. It also shows you high-rank results that omit one or more of your search terms (sometimes quietly mentioning that under the result) or that only include words it thinks are synonyms for one of your search terms (which possibly are not synonyms in the context you were looking for). All of this is extremely bad ux.

Comment: Netflix does this when they don't have the movie you were searching for--they instead show you movies that are similar to the one you were actually trying to find. I'm undecided as to whether or not I like this route.

Comment: @Ectropy: It would be so much better if they showed you the movie that you were obviously searching for, acknowledging that it exists but they don't have streaming rights to it, and indicated whether you could get it with their DVDs-by-mail service (which still exists, right?), and only then offered to show you similar movies you might like.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Perhaps you could elaborate rather than leaving a cryptic comment and -1...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: It's not always fuzzy-searching. Google seems to actively omit some of your search terms when it thinks you'll get "better" results without them, rather than using any distance function. But conceptually, fuzzy searching is also a generalization of the user's query, even if the mechanism is to generalize by admitting low-distance results.

Comment: Agreed - really, really annoying. Sometimes it's quite difficult to actually get it to give results for the thing you literally typed in. By all means suggest alternatives but _do not_ silently reword my query!!!

Comment: also yes Netflix - cognitive load when I get results for something that's _not what I searched for_ is unacceptable. If there are no results, show me no results - but then perhaps "ALSO HERE IS SOME RELATED CRAP" would be fine, just be clear about it.

Comment: Certainly, quietly/silently changing the user's query is deplorable. But providing insight into the context (or "neighbourhood") of the query's result (especially when empty) is highly valuable from the point of view of information visualization.

Answer (score 1):

I think an empty results list is just fine, when your page navigation is good.

An empty results list is consequent. It doesn't break the expectations (e.g. showing a page which doesn't look like the search page at all, like the "bummer no results" page) and conveys "here is an empty list".

The important part is your navigation. If there was a search, make sure the search field is visible above (use the same layoutfor full and empty result lists). If it was a navigation in a FAQ with categories, then make sure the needed breadcrumbs to navigate back are visible.

Do not redirect to some other page (this will break simple fixes like changing the mistyped term directly in the URL) and do not provide action buttons which are not clearly useful. When I found no answer in the FAQ category, I do not want to return to the homepage. Maybe I want to return to the FAQ index, most likely I want to return to the parent category. In search results, I most likely want to change the search term.

Comment: When I find 0 results, I want to return to their competitor's search page.